# Encryption/Decryption with Sodium extension with php 5.6 not working

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6

My Old project is on 5.6  so Sodium extension for Encryption/Decryption is not working so my system engineer set some setting that if I run file with .php7 extension it run on php 7 and normal .php run on php 5.6.

So when I need to do Encryption/Decryption I simply run api with my base use like : htps://mydoman/encode/v2/test.php7

I need to do some code that I can use direct php 7 file and do  Encryption/Decryption.

How is that possible ? with file include its not working , also I try file_get_contents but not working.

I try to run .php7 (php 7) file in normal .php (php 5.6) file but not working.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to run some PHP 7 code from inside PHP 5.6?  Since you can run PHP 7 by making http requests to `.php7` files, why not make an http request to a php7 file from your PHP 5.6 code?  Say with curl?

Comment: 1) Yes : you need to run some PHP 7 code from inside PHP 5.6

Comment: I make API file of PHP7 and I call from php.5.6 by cUrl and its work file. but see if we call every time api with internal server it will make problem as we have Request call limit. thats why I thought it will be file to run into code for encode/decode